# My popover view controller dissapears when NSStatusBar IconView image changes

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, swift

I have a status bar app which shows a green circle in the status bar and alternates to a red circle every 10 seconds. It does this by using `item.view = icon1;` and `item.view = icon2;` to change the image. Initialised like this:

```
let item = NSStatusBar.systemStatusBar().statusItemWithLength(-1);
self.icon1 = IconView(imageName: "icon1", item: item);
self.icon2 = IconView(imageName: "icon2", item: item);
```

When you click on the green or red circle, a popover view with some settings I have made appears fine.

The problem is at each 10 second interval when the `item.view` changes to either the red or the green, the popover view closes and requires the user to click the green or red button again to show it.

**How can I make the popover persist though status bar image changes and only disappear once the user clicks the red or green button again?**

Here is my `awakeFromNib()` for the popover view:

```
override func awakeFromNib()
{
    let edge = NSMinYEdge
    let icon = self.icon
    let icon2 = self.icon2
    let icon3 = self.icon3

    let rect = icon.frame
    let rect2 = icon2.frame
    let rect3 = icon3.frame


    icon.onMouseDown = {
        if (icon.isSelected)
        {
            self.popover?.showRelativeToRect(rect, ofView: icon, preferredEdge: edge);
            return
        }

        self.popover?.close()
    }

    icon2.onMouseDown = {
        if (icon2.isSelected)
        {
            self.popover?.showRelativeToRect(rect2, ofView: icon2, preferredEdge: edge);
            return
        }

        self.popover?.close()
    }

    icon3.onMouseDown = {
        if (icon3.isSelected)
        {
            self.popover?.showRelativeToRect(rect3, ofView: icon3, preferredEdge: edge);
            return
        }

        self.popover?.close()
    }



}
```

}

Comment: You have a status bar app?  Using ios and osx tags, what do you mean by that?

Answer (score 1):

You have the popover attached to a view that is later removed from the view hierarchy. Instead of assigning a new view to `NSStatusItem` each time, use a single view and change it's properties to show different states (i.e. change it's `image` property).

Alternatively you can create an empty `NSView` and assign it to `NSStatusItem` view property. Then you can add and show your icons inside that view as needed. Make sure to attach the popover to this empty view instead of individual icons.

Comment: Could you maybe help me out with the code behind it? I'm struggling to get it working even though what you're saying makes sense.

Comment: Anything would be really helpful :)

Comment: What kind of class is "IconView"? Can you change its image?

Answer (score 0):

Put a breakpoint inside the popover class `dealloc` method to see the stack trace. You'll get a hint of why this is happening from that stack trace.